# How to write complex C-style for statements in Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ezswiftextensions

How will I be able to implement a C-style `for` loop like this in Swift 2.2?

```
for var level: Double = 10; level <= 100; level += 10 {

}
```

Comment: why would you use a double for this?

Comment: Its needed inside the loop

Comment: Than loop over an int and create a double from it in the loop.

Answer (score 5):

```
for level: Double in 10.stride(through: 100, by: 10) {
}
```

or in functional style:

```
(1...10).map { Double($0) * 10.0 }.forEach {
    print($0)
}
```

Please, don't use `var` for iterators and don't change the value of an iterator from inside the loop.

I give more examples in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36180319/669586)

Comment: Quite straightforward!

Comment: Thanks. I think old version is more readable, not sure if familiarity bias or not. Functional style isn't readable at all.

Comment: @Esq In this case, I wouldn't use the functional style but it's definitely the familiarity. For functional style it really helps to give a name (e.g. `let printIndex = {... }` and then `.forEach(printIndex)`) to every closure.

Answer (score 2):

For your specific example, what Sulthan said.

More generally, for truly complex ones, any C-style `for` loop:

```
for init; cond; step { statement }
```

can be converted to `while`:

```
init
while (cond) {
  statement
  step
}
```