# Scope of index in for-in loop - swift

Tags: swift

Do I correctly understand that there is no way to pass a local variable as an index in for-in loop so that this variable will be modified after loop ends?

```
var i = 0
for i in 0..<10 {
}
print(i)

// prints "0" but I expected "10"
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33219684/cannot-assign-to-value-i-is-a-let-constant-in-swift/33219795#33219795

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct. The way you've written it, the `i` in `for i` overshadows the `var i` inside the for loop scope. This is deliberate. There are many other ways to do what you want to do, though. For example, you might write something more like this:

```
var i = 0
for _ in 0..<10 {
    i += 1
    // ...
}
```

Or use a different name:

```
var i = 0
for ii in 0..<10 {
    i = ii
    // ...
}
```

Personally, I'd be more inclined here to use a while loop:

```
var i = 0
while i < 10 {
    i += 1
    // ...
}
```

A for loop can *always* be unrolled into a while loop, so there's no loss of generality here.

Comment: There is no `++` in modern Swift, @CharlieMartin.

Comment: Starting from swift 3 there won't be ++, @ CharlieMartin.

Comment: Thanks. I figured that must be it